# Should we use a comma, a semicolon or a dash before "trust me"?

Tags: punctuation

Should we use a comma (as shown below), a semicolon or a dash before "trust me" in the first example below, and after "trust me" in the second example below?

"I don't think he'll last another year with his crazy wife, trust me."

"Trust me, I don't think he'll last another year with his crazy wife."

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is one of tone.

- Using a dash means to focus your meaning on the last section, 'trust me' (for knowing);
- a comma is mostly an aside;
- and a semicolon is mostly incorrect since 'trust me' is not really a full comment/sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you need an exclamation mark (imperative form of verb)

"I don't think he'll last another year with his crazy wife. Trust me!"

"Trust me! I don't think he'll last another year with his crazy wife."